# screnshot of uiwebview showing blank white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, crash, uiimageview

My app is working fine in `iOS 6.1` and `Xcode 4.6`. Now after i updated to `iOS 7` and xcode 5.0 the app is getting crashed.

the scenario is, in the uiwebview i want to load the url,zoom the page and capture the webview then save the screenshot into album.

in device,while capturing the page app is getting crashed

in simulator,while capturing it is storing only blank white screen into the album.it is working fine in both simulator and device if, i take screen shot without zoom.the problem occurs only in zooming the webpage and my zoom limit is maximum-scale=0.45.

width and height of the webpage:

2013-12-31 15:11:04.886 sampl[1890:70b] frame.size.width: 437.000000

2013-12-31 15:11:04.886 sampl[1890:70b] frame.size.height: 10032.000000

i'm getting this problem if my image height is exceeding 5000 pixels.

Comment: Please provide crash report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are assign images to image view via camera or galery

we need to compress the image after take image and then assign to UIImageview so that  it will not take the original image.

Heres some example code that will attempt to compress an image for you so that it doesn't exceed either a max compression or maximum file size

> CGFloat compression = 0.9f; CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f; int
>   maxFileSize = 250*1024;
>
> NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);
>
> while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression >
>   maxCompression) {
>       compression -= 0.1;
>       imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression); }